# zero value from cublas function

Tags: cuda, linear-algebra, cublas

I am trying to solve the Ax=b system using the conjugate gradient method.

I am using the example [from nvidia samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/#conjugategradient) but instead of using the cusparseScsrmv function , I am using the cublasSgemv to perform the Ax.

My problem is that the "dot" variable in cublasSdot function is zero which results in `a = r1 / dot` to be nan.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    int Rows = 80 ,Cols = 64;
    int NbElements = Rows * Cols;

    //allocate host memory
    float * A, * x, * rhs;

    A = (float *) malloc( NbElements  * (Rows + Cols)* sizeof(float) );
    x = (float *) malloc( (Rows + Cols) * sizeof(float) );
    rhs = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*  NbElements );

    //allocate device memory
    float * devA, * devx;

    cudaMalloc( &devA, NbElements * (Rows + Cols) * sizeof(float) );
    cudaMalloc( &devx, (Rows + Cols)  * sizeof(float) );

    //read Input
    FILE * theFile;
    theFile = fopen( "A", "rb" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );
    assert( NbElements * (Rows + Cols) == fread( A, sizeof(float), NbElements * (Rows + Cols) , theFile ) );
    cudaMemcpy(devA, A, NbElements *  (Rows + Cols) * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    fclose( theFile );


    const float tol = 1e-5f;
    const int max_iter = 1000;
    float a, b, na, r0, r1,dot;
    float *devAx, *devr , *devp;
    float alpha, beta, alpham1;

    for (int i = 0; i < (Rows + Cols); i++)
        x[i] = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NbElements; i++)
        rhs[i] = 1.0;

    /* Get handle to the CUBLAS context */
    cublasHandle_t cublasHandle = 0;
    cublasStatus_t cublasStatus;
    cublasStatus = cublasCreate(&cublasHandle);

    cudaMalloc((void **)&devAx, NbElements * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&devr, NbElements * sizeof(float));
    gcudaMalloc((void **)&devp, NbElements * sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(devx, x, (Rows + Cols) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(devr, rhs, NbElements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    alpha = 1.0;
    alpham1 = -1.0;
    beta = 0.0;
    r0 = 0.0;

    cublasSgemv(cublasHandle , CUBLAS_OP_N , NbElements  , (Rows + Cols) , &alpha , devA ,  NbElements  ,  devx , 1 , &beta , devAx , 1 );
    cublasSaxpy(cublasHandle,  NbElements  , &alpham1, devAx, 1, devr, 1);
    cublasStatus = cublasSdot(cublasHandle, NbElements , devr, 1, devr, 1, &r1);

    int k = 1;
    while (r1 > tol*tol && k <= max_iter)
    {
        if (k > 1)
        {
            b = r1 / r0;
            cublasStatus = cublasSscal(cublasHandle, NbElements, &b, devp, 1);
            cublasStatus = cublasSaxpy(cublasHandle,  NbElements , &alpha, devr, 1, devp, 1);

        }
        else
        {
            cublasStatus = cublasScopy(cublasHandle,  NbElements , devr, 1, devp, 1);
        }

        cublasSgemv(cublasHandle , CUBLAS_OP_N , NbElements  , (Rows + Cols) ,  &alpha , devA ,  NbElements  ,  devx , 1 , &beta , devAx , 1 );

        cublasStatus = cublasSdot(cublasHandle,  NbElements , devp, 1, devAx, 1, &dot);
        a = r1 / dot;

        cout <<"dot = "<<dot<<endl;

        cublasStatus = cublasSaxpy(cublasHandle,  NbElements , &a, devp, 1, devx, 1);
        na = -a;

        cublasStatus = cublasSaxpy(cublasHandle,  NbElements , &na, devAx, 1, devr, 1);

        r0 = r1;
        cublasStatus = cublasSdot(cublasHandle,  NbElements , devr, 1, devr, 1, &r1);

        cudaThreadSynchronize();
        cout << "\niteration = "<<k<<" , residual = "<<sqrt(r1)<<endl;
        k++;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(x, devx, (Rows + Cols) *sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cublasDestroy(cublasHandle);


    {   FILE * theFile;
        theFile = fopen( "X", "wb" );
        assert( NULL != theFile );
        fwrite( x, sizeof(float), (Rows + Cols) , theFile );
        fclose( theFile );
    }

    free(rhs);
    free( A );
    free( x );

    // clean up device memory
    cudaFree( devA );
    cudaFree( devx );
    cudaFree( devr );
    cudaFree( devp );
    cudaFree( devAx );

    return 0;
}
```

(I am loading a random matrix A ,which you can find [here](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gca4268302ccf495299951309738429a471e0d2aa0) )

Comment: 171 lines of code is *lot* of code. Especially when at least 30 of those lines were excessive white space. And how are we supposed to know what is going wrong? The code requires an input file which we do not have. PLease make your "my code doesn't work questions" short, self-contained and complete. You have asked **190** questions here on [SO], surely you understand how things work around here?

Comment: I would say that it should be easy to debug a code like this by yourself tracing back the mistake. `dot` can be zero if `devp` is zero or `devAx` is zero, or they are simultaneously zero or else they are orthogonal. Have you ascertained the reason why `dot` is zero? Understanding this could help you to locate the mistake or help others help you.

Comment: Furthermore, conjugate gradient is a standard algorithm and you will find many simple implementations, for example, in Matlab. A one-to-one checking of the CUDA and Matlab instructions could help you to construct a working code.

Comment: @talonmies:I used the shortest example I could.Most lines are for allocating memory.I edited and uploaded a file.

Comment: @talonmies:First of all ,chill out!Nobody wasted your time!If you want to help ,help,it is simple and I really thank you.But I didn't force you!And I missed one line during copy paste ,ok! (the result doesn't change because code was tested with using the file)

Comment: As @talonmies mentioned, you are still simply opening and closing the file containing the matrix `A`, but not loading it. Voting to close.

Comment: @JackOLantern:I have corrected that as I said.

Comment: I do not see any `fread` between the `fopen` and `fclose`. And I have refreshed the page. What do you have corrected?

Comment: @JackOLantern:Sorry ,it seems ,I messed up the copypaste , you had right.I added now.

Comment: This is **exactly** what @talonmies meant by **wasting time**!

Comment: @JackOLantern:I disagree.Ok, I don't say that it's ok from my side to upload a code whith some failures but in order to waste your time , it is needed first to make you see my post , to force you.I don't think I forced anyone here.

Comment: George, posting questions on StackOverflow is an implicit request for help to somebody. Any _unforced_ person that has tried to help you has wasted his time compiling and running a code that could not work. If you see one of my questions, you will find a rant from @talonmies complaining to have missed `include` files from sample codes. _Ex post_, I have to say he was right. Don't take a complain as a personal attack. If, instead of trying to defend you, you were trying to improve your post three hours ago, perhaps as of now somebody was already able to help you.

Comment: @JackOLantern:I think it's ok to defend my self as you can say your opinion.I have edited the code when talonmies told me but it seemed I did a technical mistake and didn't corrected totally.Anyway , you said somebody may was able to help me.What stops him?The negative comments?The downvote?Ok, we said it took some hours to correct the post.Later on?Personally , I wouldn't have problem to answer a question which had a wrong and later corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The `devAx` array appearing in the `cuBlasSdot` instruction

```
cublasStatus = cublasSdot(cublasHandle,  NbElements , devp, 1, devAx, 1, &dot);
```

is a vanishing vector. This is because the `devAx` array is computed at the line

```
cublasSgemv(cublasHandle , CUBLAS_OP_N , NbElements  , (Rows + Cols) , &alpha , devA ,  NbElements  ,  devx , 1 , &beta , devAx , 1 );
```

as the matrix-vector product between `devA` and `devx`. In turn, `devx` is the `cudaMemcpy` of `x` which is initialized as a vanishing vector

```
for (int i = 0; i < (Rows + Cols); i++)
    x[i] = 0.0;
```

I suspect that the rest of the code doesn't make much sense, since Conjugate Gradient should work also with vanishing initial guess.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion. It shoudn't be much of a surprise that [A]{x} = {0} when {x}={0}.... I was expecting something a little more subtle, like the input matrix not being SPD or something but given whose question this is, I suppose even that is expecting an unrealistic degree of sophistication

Comment: @talonmies I think there is also a misinterpretation of the method, since the Conjugate Gradient requires the matrix `A` to be positive definite, a result that is achieved by multiplying the linear system by the adjoint of `A`. Furthermore, I do not think that the routine is algorithmically correct and I would suggest the OP to go through [Conjugate gradient method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).

Comment: @JackOLantern:You are right.I just followed the cuda example which uses also devx ,which is copied from x.Anyway , I will check it these days,thanks.